# Can't Read JSON - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I've been struggling with this issue for quite a while now. When I try to console.log a JSON proprty, the following error shows up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'timelineData' of undefined
```

This is what my JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "default": {
    "timelineData": [{
      "time": "1359676800",
      "formattedTime": "Feb 1, 2013",
      "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 1, 2013",
      "value": [51],
      "hasData": [true],
      "formattedValue": ["51"]
    }, {
      "time": "1359763200",
      "formattedTime": "Feb 2, 2013",
      "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 2, 2013",
      "value": [53],
      "hasData": [true],
      "formattedValue": ["53"]
    }, {
      "time": "1359849600",
      "formattedTime": "Feb 3, 2013",
      "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 3, 2013",
      "value": [53],
      "hasData": [true],
      "formattedValue": ["53"]
    }],
    "averages": []
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling for data:

```
console.log(results.default.timelineData[0].time);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps I am interpreting this JSON object incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `results` set to?

Comment: Works for me, maybe as Pushkin said the variable results is not set to the right value? Maybe timelineData isn't always set?

Comment: Perhaps it actually is a JSON string rather than an object. Do you need to parse it with `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @Mark_M Thanks for the help that worked for me. Dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: @Hashim I added answer, hope it will work as per the expectation. Thanks.

Comment: There is something missing in the context. You may checkout here that your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/9gbtu0e4/ .  I guess you are referencing : "results.default.timelineData[0].time" prior it has data.

Answer (score 3):

**Observation :**

`results` is looking like an `array` instead of `object`.

**DEMO**

```js
var results = [{
 "default": {
  "timelineData": [{
   "time": "1359676800",
   "formattedTime": "Feb 1, 2013",
   "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 1, 2013",
   "value": [51],
   "hasData": [true],
   "formattedValue": ["51"]
  }, {
   "time": "1359763200",
   "formattedTime": "Feb 2, 2013",
   "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 2, 2013",
   "value": [53],
   "hasData": [true],
   "formattedValue": ["53"]
  }, {
   "time": "1359849600",
   "formattedTime": "Feb 3, 2013",
   "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 3, 2013",
   "value": [53],
   "hasData": [true],
   "formattedValue": ["53"]
  }],
  "averages": []
 }
}];

console.log(results.default.timelineData[0].time);
```

Hence, to access the `time` you should use like this :

```js
var results = [{
 "default": {
  "timelineData": [{
   "time": "1359676800",
   "formattedTime": "Feb 1, 2013",
   "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 1, 2013",
   "value": [51],
   "hasData": [true],
   "formattedValue": ["51"]
  }, {
   "time": "1359763200",
   "formattedTime": "Feb 2, 2013",
   "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 2, 2013",
   "value": [53],
   "hasData": [true],
   "formattedValue": ["53"]
  }, {
   "time": "1359849600",
   "formattedTime": "Feb 3, 2013",
   "formattedAxisTime": "Feb 3, 2013",
   "value": [53],
   "hasData": [true],
   "formattedValue": ["53"]
  }],
  "averages": []
 }
}];

console.log(results[0].default.timelineData[0].time);
```